# Substitute for assert.equal()

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, equality

I'm getting to know Mocha and so I was reading through the `assert` library documentation and noticed in the Node.js documentation for the [`.equal()`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_equal_actual_expected_message) method that it is being replaced by `.strictEqual()`. However, I see no mention of another method that we can use to test for loose equality, so what does that mean? We'll just have to write a good ol'condition with a `==` operator instead?

Comment: The `equal()` method isn't going anywhere, otherwise it would be marked deprecated. It is currently marked _"Stability: 3 - Legacy. Although this feature is unlikely to be removed and is still covered by semantic versioning guarantees, it is no longer actively maintained, and other alternatives are available."_

Comment: An alternative would be `assert.ok("1" == 1)` which tests any _truthy_ value

Comment: "In Legacy assertion mode, changed status from Deprecated to Legacy." @Phil it was deprecated, and legacy sounds like an even lower tier than depreacted

Comment: Note that `.equal()` is "An alias of assert.strictEqual()." when in `"use strict";` mode

Comment: @Samathingamajig bit of a difference between `"use strict"` and `import assert from 'node:assert/strict';`. The latter is absolutely intentional

Comment: @Samathingamajig "*legacy sounds like an even lower tier than depreacted*" no, it's not: https://nodejs.org/api/documentation.html#stability-index Legacy is different. It's basically there because it was there before. And it's unlikely to be removed. Just not maintained.